# Translate network mount command to fstab

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

I've got the following **working** mount command:

```
mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/git/.smbcredentials,sec=ntlm //SRV010/Service\ Center\$/Informatie\ Management/Development /home/git/repositories
```

This works just fine, the network file gets mounted just fine. Now using `nano /etc/fstab` I'm trying to get this to work. My attempt is as followed:

```
//SRV010/Service\ Center\$/Informatie\ Management/Development /home/git/repositories cifs credentials=/home/git/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

but then I get the following error:

> mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 13. 
>   mount: can't find repositories/ in /etc/fstab

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just solved my own question...

Apparently spaces are not escaped by simply using \ in fstab. Replacing

```
//SRV010/Service\ Center\$/Informatie\ Management/Development
```

with

```
//SRV010/Service\040Center$/Informatie\040Management/Development
```

fixed the problem.